# Bind Element to controls SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm trying to show some data retrieved by Odata Model on a XML View.
In Component.js, I create a model with service Url and it works as usual.

```
    var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("http://server:port/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZWYMB_SRV", {
            user:"abapleader",
            password: "TH123456789a@",
            headers: {
                "sap-client": 300
            },
            useBatch:false
        });          
        this.setModel(oDataModel, "oDataModel");
```

So far, I've managed to get data to master using `model.read()` function.

Now I need to show the detail view. My code for `onInit` event is below:

```
            this.router.getRoute("zwm01detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched.bind(this));

        },
        _onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
            var that = this;
        var MaWorkDoc = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").MaWorkDoc;
            this.getModel("oDataModel").metadataLoaded().then(function() {
                var sPath = that.getModel("oDataModel").createKey("/WorkDocList", {
                    MaWorkDoc: MaWorkDoc,
                    Pernr: "0001"
                });
                console.log(sPath);
                that.getView().bindElement({
                    path:sPath
                });
            });
```

The `sPath` as I printed out using `console.log(sPath)` : /WorkDocList(MaWorkDoc='1110000001',Pernr='0001'), which I think, is correct. I also implemented and tested the back-end using this path and basically things are fine. But I don't know why I cannot show data on the view.

Detail.view.xml:

```
<Text text="{/MaWorkDoc}" maxLines="0"/>
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Does the path syntax using parenthesis have a specific name ? I'm trying to achieve something similar like `"/bins(binid='" + oArgs.binid + "')"` but can't make it work :/

Answer (score 1):

Because you have given your model a name you will need to use that name in the binding. i.e. `<Text text="{oDataModel>/MaWorkDoc}" maxLines="0"/>`

Comment: Sir I've already tried add oDataModel> but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the detail binding code should be inside the .metadataLoaded handler. Rather it should be directly inside _onObjectMatched.

I mean like this.

```
 _onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
        var that = this;
        var MaWorkDoc = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").MaWorkDoc;
        var sPath = that.getModel("oDataModel").createKey("/WorkDocList", {
                MaWorkDoc: MaWorkDoc,
                Pernr: "0001"
            });
            console.log(sPath);
            that.getView().bindElement({
                path:sPath
            });
        }
```

Comment: Could you please be more detail sir? How do I implement the _onObjectMatched event in my code? Sorry If it makes you feel uncomfortable but I'm totally new in this.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

So I've been working around with the docs and figure out there is `model` parameter which helps.

To be more specific, I add declare `model` in `view.bindElement` as below:

```
that.getView().bindElement({
                    path:sPath,
//** oDataModel = name of the model
                    model: "oDataModel"
                });
```

If there is any better solution, I'd very glad to know it. Thank you.!